# How to stop Catalina from continually telling me I need to sign in again?

Tags: macos, icloud, apple-id, catalina

Ugraded to Catalina 10.15. The doc shows a little notification icon above the System Preferences App

[image]

Opening the System Preferences shows this

[image]

So I click continue which gives me this

[image]

So I click continue which brings me here

[image]

I enter my password. About 7 seconds later the notification disppears

[image]

But 5 seconds after that this appears

[image]

Everything seems fine but then 15 seconds later the notification at the top appears again. Have repeated 4 times now. This happens on both my Macs

How do I fix this so it stops asking?

Comment: Did you sign out entirely? There was a question recently that covered this - could be a quick fix if you’re willing to try that.

Comment: That seemed to work though it was really annoying as it tried to start syncing a bunch of stuff I'd had off before signing out. Cross my fingers it stays.

Comment: Yup. Annoying for sure. Glad it sorted things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If signing in several times doesn’t resolve this and you can’t or won’t wait it out, signing out completely appears to get this prompt to go away.

- [iCloud Keychain refuses to setup on Catalina](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367277/icloud-keychain-refuses-to-setup-on-catalina)

You do of course have to deal with the side effects of signing out like choosing to delete or keep local copies of iCloud data and then setting up your iCloud preferences and settings.

If you have a good backup, you could also try force quitting the system preferences app before you log out of the account.